# Django: cannot unpack non-iterable Posts object (TypeError)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to filter the elements present in the "Posts" model by one of their attributes.

This is my Class Based View:

```
class FilteredPostListView(ListView):
model = Posts
template_name = "blog/post-category.html"
context_object_name = "posts"
paginate_by = 6

#the actual fuction that should filter the element by their category attribute: 
def get_queryset(self):
    category = get_object_or_404(Posts, category=self.kwargs.get("category")) 
    return Posts.objects.filter(category)
```

This is the related snippet in my urls.py:

```
path('category/<category>/', FilteredPostListView.as_view(), name='category')
```

When I type the URL localhost:8000/category/example/  where "example" is the value of the "category" attribute I am trying to filter by, I get the following errors:

If multiple Posts objects have the attribute category with value "example":

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /category/example/
get() returned more than one Posts -- it returned 2!
```

If only one Posts object has the attribute category with the value "example":

```
TypeError at /category/example/
cannot unpack non-iterable Posts object
```

Why is it returning non-iterable objects?

UPDATE:

if the `def get_queryset()` method is changed to a more simplified version with the value of the attribute "category" hardcoded in like this one:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Posts.objects.filter(category="example")
```

Then the code runs flawlessly, and the Class based view returns iterable objects that have the attribute "category" set to "example", and that can be displayed in the template with a `for` codeblock.

But I can't hardcode the value of the attribute "category" everytime that I want to filter my "Posts" objects by the attribute.

So the problem lies in the more complex version of the method:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.kwargs.get("category")
        return Posts.objects.filter(category).order_by("-date_posted")
```

That for some reason is returning not iterable objects.

Comment: What exactly do you want your function to do: (a) if more than one object exists, (b) if one object exists, (c) if no object exists?

Comment: The aim is to pass the Posts objects that are returned to the template and display them with a for loop codeblock. If no objects exists it should return 404, that is the purpose of the "get_object_or_404()" method. But if one or more objects with the specified category attribute exist, then the aim is to display them in the template with a for loop.